# Safari: the BACK button doesn't work

Tags: safari

In general, my back button works fine, as does everything else in Safari.

But there is one webpage (an online quiz for a class) which opened in a popup window, I filled in my responses, hit the submit button, and then it told me my session is expired.  In this window, the keyboard shortcut for Back doesn't do anything and right-clicking on the page gives a context menu with Forward but not Back.

Is there any way for me to go Back to see my long hard work of entering responses in the form on the previous page?

Comment: Since it was popped up in a new window, and when you hit submit it failed, then there's probably nothing to go "back" to, as you didn't actually leave the page.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to if you disable javascript.  Here is a [link](http://whatismyipaddress.ricmedia.com/help/JavaScript/safari/) on how to do it on a Mac.  Some websites use javascript to disable the back button.  However, they usually do this for a reason.  Many online quizzes like this disable the back button to prevent cheating, or it could be the way the website was developed, using the back button might break the quiz.